# "Mark Up" all non-blank cells (excluding header row)

Tags: vba, excel, loops, foreach, do-while

I have a sheet (say Sheet2) that has a table in it with data throughout.

In the below sample (much smaller than the actual data), it would need to select every value from B2:O2 down and if there is a value in there (ignoring all blank cells randomly placed with no data), then increase the amount by 15% of previous cell.

Range is from B:O, though not every cell has a value. Column A has ID values that would be a count for how long each column is.

So cell B2 output would be 11.5, C2 would be 1.15 as shown below:

**Before code run.**

```
Row Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D ... Column O
 1      ID#     Header1     Header2     Header3   'Row(1) header
 2      ID1         10                       1
 3      ID2          2           5           
 4      ID3                                  2
```

**After code run.**

```
Row Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D ... Column O
 1      ID#     Header1     Header2     Header3   'Row(1) header
 2      ID1         11.5                    1.15
 3      ID2         2.3         5.75           
 4      ID3                                 2.3
```

I don't know how to do it with using For Each Loop? Thanks in advance!

Comment: let me confirm. blank cell (means '-' cell) can have only in column C or both column (B and C)?

Comment: Blank cells are random and throughout the whole sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to change the increment change Inc_By to the decimal you need. e.g. 0.15 is 15% 0.45 is 45%
The below assumes that "-" is really ""

```
Sub test()

Inc_By = 0.15

With ActiveSheet
    lCol = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    For Each cell In .Range("A2:" & .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Address)
        For i = 2 To lCol
            If .Cells(cell.Row, i) <> "" Then
                .Cells(cell.Row, i).Value = .Cells(cell.Row, i).Value + (.Cells(cell.Row, i).Value * Inc_By)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

If the "-" is really a "-" in your spreadsheet replace below

```
If cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "" Then
```

with

```
 If cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "-" Then
```

Comment: Thanks @99moorem though the above code seems to give an incorrect output.

Comment: @Stacker Your Input/Output's have changed since your first post, Never the less I have amended above code. above will work for any amount of headers

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me if anyone else needs the same answer:

```
Sub Test()
On Error GoTo ErrorMsg
Dim l As Integer, f As Integer, c As Integer, cf As Integer, cl As Integer

l = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  'Total Rows, count from ID Column
f = 1       'First Row with Headings, is skipped with Offset
c = f       'Counter for Loop
cf = 2      'First Column to MarkUp
cl = 4      'Last Column to be MarkUp

Inc_By = 1.15   'Markup Amount

With ActiveSheet

Do While cf <= cl       'Loop count to check every Column
Cells(f, cf).Activate   'Select first cell of Column
    For Each cell In .Range(Cells(f, cf).Address, Cells(l, cf).Address)   'cf needs to be a variable and cycle through to cl
    If ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value > 0 And Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) Then 'Skips negatives and blanks
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value * Inc_By
    Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    End If

    Next

cf = cf + 1             'Counter to start searching next Column    
Loop
End With


MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```